# XSD: reuse sub-elements of complexType?

Tags: xml, xsd

I have defined the following two types in my XSD-file:

```
<complexType name="primitive">
  <attribute name="seq_num" type="int"/>
  <element name="prim_to" type="int"/>
</complexType>


<complexType name="configdata">
  <sequence>
    <element name="enable" type="boolean"/>
    <element name="type" default="int"/>
   </sequence>
</complexType>
```

Both types are used in a number of definitions, i.e. I would rather not change these them. I would like to define a new element `set` which extends `primitive` and contains all sub-elements of `configdata`. The XML-file for this element would look like this (please note, that `enable` and `type` are at the same level as `prim_to`):

```
<set seq_num="1234">
  <prim_to>22</prim_to>
  <enable>true<enable>
  <type>42</type>
</set>
```

I could declare `set` the following way:

```
<element name="set">
  <complexType>
    <complexContent>
      <extension base="primitive">
        <sequence>
          <element name="config" type="configdata"/>
        </sequence>
      </extension>
    </complexContent>
  </complexType>
</element>
```

In this case the XML-file would look like this:

```
<set seq_num="1234">
  <prim_to>22</prim_to>
  <config>
    <enable>true<enable>
    <type>42</type>
  </config>
</set>
```

My challenge is to define `set` in such a way that it extends `primitive` and contains all sub-elements of `configdata` - but does not contain an element of the type `configdata`. Basically for the XML-file above it is a question of not having the two 'config'-tags. Is this possible in XSD? I would highly appreciate any hints.

Thanks in Advance,
Witek

Comment: I must have misundertood: why don't you define set with the configdata type, eg element name="set" type="configdata" ?

Comment: I have simplified the code example compared to the real code. In my real code _set_ is an extension of another complexType. _set_ hold additional elements - and I would like it to also hold all sub-elements of _configdata_.

Comment: So what you're really asking for here is to have the set element, extend multiple complex types?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear - maybe I over-simplified the code examples. I have tried rephrasing the question to make it more clear. I hope that helps. I am learing XSD by doing - so maybe that is the root cause of my problem. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A type can only extend a single other one (in other words, there is no multiple inheritance). So, your set element can extend configdata (with xsd:extension) and have additional elements, or it can extend another type and you could copy configdata elements to extend it. You can use groups to avoid redundancy.

Comment: It could help you if you don't want to have several definitions for configdata elements: you could define a named group with all configdata elements, use it to define configdata with the tree element>complexType>group, and then use it to extend the primitive type in the set element, with the tree element>complexType>complexContent>extension>group.

Comment: That works ... and I have learned more about XSD! ;-) Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You should define the `set` element like this:

```
<element name="set" type="configdata" />
```

Using this structure, the `set` element will contain the two child elements in the configdata complex type.